# Create a policy using Android Management API - Quickstart Colab

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I'm trying to implement Android Management API for my Android project `Work profile`. [this](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart) link provides a Quickstart guide to enroll an enterprise, create a policy, and provision a device.

The Quickstart is a `Colab notebook` written in Python I guess (as the error suggests). I've successfully created an enterprise in this colab notebook, to create a basic policy I need to run this code

```
import json

policy_name = enterprise_name + '/policies/policy1'

policy_json = '''
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    }
  ],
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true
}
'''

androidmanagement.enterprises().policies().patch(
    name=policy_name,
    body=json.loads(policy_json)
).execute()
```

and this is the error I'm getting as I press run icon:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-fa6c551fe8df> in <module>()
     17 androidmanagement.enterprises().policies().patch(
     18     name=policy_name,
---> 19     body=json.loads(policy_json)
     20 ).execute()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in method(self, **kwargs)
    740             raise TypeError(
    741                 'Parameter "%s" value "%s" does not match the pattern "%s"' %
--> 742                 (name, pvalue, regex))
    743 
    744     for name, enums in six.iteritems(parameters.enum_params):

TypeError: Parameter "name" value "LC01gzjgxa/policies/policy1" does not match the pattern "^enterprises/[^/]+/policies/[^/]+$"
```

Can someone help me solve this error?

Comment: TypeError: Parameter "name" value "LC01gzjgxa/policies/policy1" does not match the pattern "^enterprises/[^/]+/policies/[^/]+$"   As per this your enterprise_name  and policy name not matching

Comment: this error is with the value or pattern?

Comment: I think with pattern, it should be something like this enterprises/LC01gzjgxa/policies/policy1

Comment: That worked! Thankyou so much :) Before using enterprise_name need to append 'enterprises/'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: Parameter "name" value "LC01gzjgxa/policies/policy1" does
>   not match the pattern "^enterprises/[^/]+/policies/[^/]+$"

As per this error log,  your enterprise_name and policy name not matching with the pattern which is expected.

it should be something like this  `enterprises/enterprise_name/policies/policy_name` .  So try to change it like below.

```
 enterprises/LC01gzjgxa/policies/policy1
```